# Word for the ability to deliver clever replies?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

What do we call the person who comes back with clever replies when someone insults them?

Also what is this ability (personality trait) to cleverly thrash rivals on-the-spot called?

> *Example:*
>
> Person A: "I can't bear fools."
>
> Person B: "Apparently, your mother could..."

What should I call Person B in this?

What is the personality trait he possesses that made him comeback so cleverly against the insult?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### witty (adjective)

### wit (noun)

These words describe the ability to make quick, sharp, clever comebacks.

Winston Churchill was famous for his quick and biting wit:

*Member of Parliament, Nancy Astor, speaking to Winston Churchill:*

> **If I were your wife I would poison your coffee..**

*Churchill:*

> **If you were my wife, I would drink it.**

---

*Member of Parliament, Bessie Braddock, speaking to Churchill:*

> **Winston, you are drunk, and what’s more you are disgustingly drunk.**

*Churchill:*

> **My dear, you are ugly, and what’s more, you are disgustingly ugly. But tomorrow I shall be sober and you will still be disgustingly ugly.**

References:

- [wit definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wit) ~ Merriam-Webster
- [Churchill's Clever Wit](https://winstonchurchill.org/the-life-of-churchill/life/man-of-words/churchill-the-wit/) ~ International Churchill Society
- [Winston Churchill tops poll of history's funniest insults](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/home-news/my-dear-you-are-ugly-but-tomorrow-i-shall-be-sober-and-you-will-still-be-ugly-winston-churchill-tops-8878622.html) ~ independent.co.uk

Comment: And *quick witted*.

Comment: "I used to think you were a wit. Then I discovered I was only half right ..."

Comment: https://youtu.be/VZJZh2ZTOqs

Comment: Riposte is a quick and clever reply.

Comment: The second quote is also attributed to Bessie Braddock (see https://richardlangworth.com/drunk-ugly-braddock) and seems to be adapted from a W. C. Fields movie (https://www.quotes.net/mquote/47812).  However, another source claims they're both apocryphal (https://www.bartleby.com/73/2004.html).  Churchill is one of those exceptional folk to whom all quotes eventually get attributed…

Comment: @gidds, agreed. I've found that many quotes attributed to Winston Churchill, Benjamin Franklin, Mahatma Ghandi, Nelson Mandela, Henry Ford and other famous historical figures are disputed or can't be verified. I tend to stick with the conventional attribution for general purposes if it portrays them in a positive light.

Answer (score 6):

[Rapier wit](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/rapier-wit) is slightly different from witty: there's a (sharp) rapier in mind.

Rapier wit:

> ability to deliver witty and cutting remarks

A [rapier](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/rapier) is a very thin sword with a long, sharp point.

Answer (score 3):

As in: (for a single word)

Person A: "I can't bear fools."

Person B: "Apparently, your mother could!"

Person A: "Ouch ... you are **quick**."

**quick**  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/156418?rskey=w904xD&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> Of a person: mentally agile; prompt to think; of ready wit.

Answer (score 0):

> **derisive**
>   *adjective* characterized by or expressing derision; contemptuous; mocking: derisive heckling.

Example: *The message is derisive—rhabdomyolysis and whatever else might happen to certain people is really for wimps and buffoons only.*
COOL IT ON THE CROSSFIT: WHAT’S RHABDOMYOLYSIS?|KENT SEPKOWITZ|OCTOBER 11, 2013|DAILY BEAST

> **wry**
>   *adjective* bitterly or disdainfully ironic or amusing: a wry remark.

Example: *But Beard was, as Beard would have put it, "wry," which is the word people like Beard use when they mean funny.*
DOUG KENNEY: THE ODD COMIC GENIUS BEHIND ‘ANIMAL HOUSE’ AND NATIONAL LAMPOON

> **sardonic**
>   *adjective* characterized by bitter or scornful derision; mocking; cynical; sneering: a sardonic grin.

Example: *Ebert was celebrated for the sardonic wit and democratic writing style he employed in his reviews.*
ROGER EBERT, 70, HAS DIED: A LOOK AT THE LIFE OF CINEMA’S GREAT APPRECIATOR|MARLOW STERN|APRIL 4, 2013|DAILY BEAST

(source: dictionary.com, thesaurus.com)

Answer (score 0):

In the UK, this is called 'quick-witted'.
Refer to this description of comedian Paul Merton:- 
http://www.therightaddress.co.uk/paul-merton